# How to use Mikolajczyk evaluation for detectors/descriptors?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

I want to compare different detectors/descriptors (**both binaries and not**) for my application and I want to use the [Mikolajczyk evaluation framework](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/desc_evaluation.html#code), which is became a standard in the community about this kind of evaluation.

The region input format must be of the form:

```
%descriptor_size  
%nbr_of_regions
%x1 y1 a1 b1 c1 d1 d2 d3 ...
%x2 y2 a2 b2 c2 d1 d2 d3 ...
%....
%....
%---------------------
%x, y - center coordinates
%a, b, c - ellipse parameters ax^2+2bxy+cy^2=1
%d1 d2 d3 ... - descriptor invariants
%if descriptor_size<=1 the descriptor is ignored
```

(I'll use it later)

Anyway, I find quite difficult to use it from OpenCV since I didn't find any example/tutorial where it is used, so I have some questions:

1. There is any example/tutorial where it is used from OpenCV to matlab? Could you provide one otherwise?
2. This framework can be used also for binary detectors/descriptors?
3. There is any equivalent tool in OpenCV?
4. Is it correct to say that when we want to evaluate a detector we set `descriptor_size=1` while we set `descriptor_size=128` when we want to evaluate SIFT's descriptor (for example)?